# PHP show array of short months as a range

Tags: php, date

I need to show an array of short month dates as a range. I.e. Where there is an array of consecutive months, output the lowest and highest month and place the text "to" between them.

e.g. array 'Feb, Mar, Apr,  May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct'

output as 'Feb to Oct'

And if there is more than one group of consecutive months, do the above for each group

e.g. array 'Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Aug, Sep, Oct'

output as 'Feb to May, Aug to Oct'

I've got so far with the below code but the output is missing out certain months.  i.e. the below code outputs 'Mar, May, Aug, Oct'

```
$seasons_raw = 'Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Aug, Sep, Oct';
$seasons_arr = explode(",",$seasons_raw);
$seasons_numeric = array();
$seasons_ranges = array();
$group_id = 0;
$last = false;
foreach($seasons_arr as $season_raw){
    $month = (int)date('m', strtotime($season_raw));
    if($month - $last > 1){
        $group_id++;
    }   
    $seasons_numeric[$group_id][] = $month;
    $last = $month;
}

foreach($seasons_numeric as $season_section){
    $first_obj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $season_section[0]);
    $last_obj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $season_section[count($season_section)-1]);
    if($first_obj == $last_obj){
        $seasons_ranges[] = $first_obj->format('M');
    }
    else{
        $seasons_ranges[] = $first_obj->format('M') . ' to ' . $last_obj->format('M');
    }
}
$seasons = implode(', ',$seasons_ranges);
echo $seasons;
```

Thanks

Comment: *".. is missing our months"* - What does that mean?

Comment: @GolezTrol - Spelling error sorry, should have been".. is missing out months" . i.e. the above code outputs Mar, May, Aug, Oct

Comment: have you or can you define the rules that you use to split at a certain point?

Comment: @RamRaider - If the months are consecutive then take the highest and lowest month and place the text "to" between them e.g. 'Feb, Mar, Apr, May,' would display as 'Feb to May'

Comment: thankyou for the clarification

Comment: Would there ever be a situation where you are looking at multiple non-consecutive ranges, such as `Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Nov, Dec` which would have 3 such non-consecutive ranges to process?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$input = 'Jan, Feb, Mar, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Dec';

$month_number = array_flip(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul', 'Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']);

$input = array_map(function($m) { return trim($m); }, explode(',',$input));

$groups = [];

while ( $current = current($input) ) {
    $start = $current;
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $next = next($input);
        $i++;
    } while ( $next && $month_number[$next] == $month_number[$current] + $i );
    $stop = $next ? prev($input) : end($input);
    $groups[] = [$start, $stop];
    next($input);
}

echo implode(', ', array_map(function($group) {
    return $group[0] == $group[1] ? $group[0] : sprintf('%s to %s', $group[0], $group[1]);
}, $groups));
```

This will output:

> Jan to Mar, May to Oct, Dec

Answer (score 1):

This does not work.

```
$month = (int)date('m', strtotime($season_raw));
```

Replaced with a custom function:

```
<?php

function debugout($msg) {
    echo "DEBUG: " . $msg . "\n";
}
function monthToNum($monthString) {
    $m = ['Jan' => 1, 'Feb' => 2, 'Mar' => 3, 'Apr' => 4, 'May' => 5, 'Jun' => 6, 
    'Jul' => 7, 'Aug' => 8, 'Sep' => 9, 'Oct' => 10, 'Nov' => 11, 'Dec' => 12];
    return $m[trim($monthString)] ?? null;
}
$seasons_raw = 'Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Aug, Sep, Oct';
$seasons_arr = explode(",",$seasons_raw);
$seasons_numeric = array();
$seasons_ranges = array();
$group_id = 0;
$last = false;
foreach($seasons_arr as $season_raw){

    // $month = (int)date('m', strtotime($season_raw));
    $month = monthToNum($season_raw);
    if ( empty($month) ) {
        // Check just in case
        throw new Exception("Bad month string {$season_raw}");
    }
    debugout("month  '{$season_raw}' -> '{$month}'");

    if($month - $last > 1){
        $group_id++;
    }   
    $seasons_numeric[$group_id][] = $month;
    $last = $month;
}

foreach($seasons_numeric as $season_section){
    $first_obj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $season_section[0]);
    $last_obj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $season_section[count($season_section)-1]);
    if($first_obj == $last_obj){
        $seasons_ranges[] = $first_obj->format('M');
    }
    else{
        $seasons_ranges[] = $first_obj->format('M') . ' to ' . $last_obj->format('M');
    }
}
$seasons = implode(', ',$seasons_ranges);
echo $seasons;
```

Answer (score 1):

So long as there are not ever to be multiple non-consecutive ranges used the below code more or less accomplishes the goal, probably not as refined as it could be for sure. I could see no need to actually use any `date` or `DateTime` functions given the input data so this just works on the arrays.

```
function makerange( $str=false ){
    if( $str ){

        $tmp=$out=array();
        $linear=true;

        $year = explode( ',', 'Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec' );
        $months = explode( ',', $str );

        array_walk( $year, function( &$item ){ $item=trim( $item );});
        array_walk( $months, function( &$item ){ $item=trim( $item );});

        foreach( $months as $month ){
            $tmp[]=array_search( $month, $year );
        }


        foreach( $tmp as $key => $month ){
            if( $key > 0 && $key < count( $tmp ) - 1 ) {
                if( $tmp[ $key + 1 ] - $month > 1 ){
                    $linear=false; break;
                }
            }
        }

        if( !empty( $tmp ) ){

            $out[]=$year[ $tmp[0] ];

            if( !$linear ){
                $out[]=$year[ $tmp[ $key ] ];
                $out[]=$year[ $tmp[ $key + 1 ] ];
            }
            $out[]=$year[ $tmp[ count( $tmp ) - 1 ] ];



            $bits=array_chunk( $out, 2 );

            if( !$linear ){
                $from=implode( '-', $bits[ 0 ] );
                $to=implode( '-', $bits[ 1 ] );

                return sprintf('From: %s To: %s', $from, $to );
            } else {
                $from = implode( '-', $bits[ 0 ] );

                return sprintf('Linear range: %s ', $from );
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


$str='Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Aug, Sep, Oct';
printf('%s<br/>%s<br/><br/>', $str, makerange( $str ) );

$str='Jan, Feb, Mar, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct';
printf('%s<br/>%s<br/><br/>', $str, makerange( $str ) );
```

The above will output

```
Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Aug, Sep, Oct
From: Feb-Jun To: Aug-Oct

Jan, Feb, Mar, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct
From: Jan-Mar To: May-Oct
```

Answer (score -2):

Write a simple function like the following and then call it wherever you want it.

```
function ShowMonths($start, $finish = 12)
{
  # lets seed month 0 with a NULL so the months can be 1-12
  $month[] = NULL;
  for ($i=1;$i<13;$i++) {
      $month[] = date('M', strtotime('01.'.$i.'.2000'));
  }
    if ($start < 0 || $start > 11) {
        die("Start month incorrect");
    }
    if ($finish < 1 || $finish > 12) {
        die("Finish wrong");
    }
    if ($start >= $finish) {
        die("Finish larger than start");
    }
    print $month[$start] . " to " . $month[$finish];
}

ShowMonths(1, 2);
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem; the given input data this is supposed to work on is the string value `Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct`

Comment: The above actually asked for outputs in the original question. Nowhere did it say what the input was to be...

Comment: Of course it did: _"I need to show an array of short month dates as a range. [...] e.g. array 'Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct'"_